# How to "style" a text based hangman game

Tags: python, terminal, text-based

My question is simple, the hangman game looks like this:

[image]

I'm doing the indentation in a way I don't think is very good.

I just have `var = "\t"` and add it at the begging of every print, this seem impractical and hard to maintain.

Would you have it any other way? How is this generally managed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @belisarius: hehe nice, somebody stole my karma!! Tell me whenever you are around I wan't to tell you something related.

Answer (score 1):

problem:

```
print('\tthis')
print('\tis')
print('\tan')
print('\texample')
```

solution = abstraction!:

```
def echo(string, indent=1):  # name it whatever you want, e.g. p
    print('\t'*indent + string)

echo('this')
echo('is')
echo('an')
echo('abstraction')
```

better solution = templates:

```
template = """
{partial}
 ______
{hangman}
|_________

Your points so far: {points}
You've entered (wrong): {wrong}

Choose a letter:
"""

print(
    template.format(
        partial=..., 
        hangman='\n'.join('|'+line for line in hangmanAscii(wrong=2).splitlines()), 
        points=..., 
        wrong=', '.join(...)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Templates](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) aren't *just* for HTML.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, I had really no idea I'm checking it out, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably fix the typo in "You word looks like this". Then look at `printf` style formatting, as described [here](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html).

Comment: heh thanks for the typo warning, what `printf` are you talking about? I know what formatted string are, but doing `"%sYour word looks like this"`%"\t" is more or less the same. I did not understand! Thansk!

Comment: Well a good practice is to keep your formatting and data separate, and this is a mechanism for doing so. e.g. `print "\tYour points so far: %d" % points` - the formatting is all in one place and the data is all in one place. I wouldn't put the tab in a variable.

Comment: PS: Templates (as suggested by Ignacio) provide a different mechanism to achieve the same result. Use what works for you!

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution to your immediate problem is a helper function:

```
def put(text): print "\t" + text
```

For more interesting stuff, there is a library for terminal-based "graphical"-like applications. It is called "curses", and is available in python too: http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html. There is a tutorial here http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html, and you can find more online.

Curses makes it possible to do more interesting text-based UI without too much effort. To just replicate what you have, you would probably create a window with the correct size and position (using `newwin`), and then print text to it without any indent (using `addstr`). Curses offers a lot of options and several modes of operation. It's not quick to learn, so only makes sense if you plan to do more with terminal based applications.

Comment: I'd +1 this for the helper function, but suggesting someone use curses is just mean.. :-)